# Chart.js label color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to create a bar chart and can't seem to change the label colors or the legend colors. I figured out how to change the tick colors, but I'm not sure where to put the 'scaleFontColor', if that is indeed what I need to be using.

Here is a link to what it looks like now.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmdwT.jpg

And here is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    scaleFontColor: "white",
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($timeSlice); ?>, 
        datasets: [{
            label: "A Label",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(159,170,174,0.8)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(232,105,90,0.8)",
            hoverBorderColor: "orange",
            scaleStepWidth: 1,
            data: <?php echo json_encode($myCount); ?>
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            fontColor: "white"
        },
        scales: { 
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    stepSize: 1,
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Guh I solved it, sorry about the question. But I guess I'll leave an answer in case anyone else runs into my problem.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: ["label 1", "label 2"], 
            datasets: [{
                label: "My Label",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(159,170,174,0.8)",
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(232,105,90,0.8)",
                hoverBorderColor: "orange",
                scaleStepWidth: 1,
                  data: [4, 5]
            }]
        },
        options: { 
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    fontColor: "blue",
                    fontSize: 18
                }
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "green",
                        fontSize: 18,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "purple",
                        fontSize: 14,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
   <!-- Edit:
   chart.js recently released new version v3.x
   which is not backwards compatible with v2.x
   -->

<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>-->

   <!-- above link gets you latest version of chart.js (at v3.3.2 now)
        hence snippet didn't work propperly anymore :-(
   -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>

   <!-- above link gets you v2.9.4
        and snippet works agian  :-)
   -->

<div>
    <canvas id="barChart" height="140"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work for 1 label, how about mutliple?

Comment: @Allart Yeah, I wish I could figure that out!

Comment: @PhantomSalt and @João Pimentel Ferreira  Good question and good answer and Edit. Snippet is working only partially because chart.js released update **v3.x** which is not backwards compatible with **v2.x**  . If you replace source link to `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>` snippet would work again. Hence, your code would be the working solution for chart.js **v2.x** and underneath I added modification to your code for chart.js **v3.x** for those interested.

Comment: font color can be set by "color" instead of "fontColor"

Answer (score 56):

Good question and good answer from @PhantomSalt

His answer works perfectly well with ....... `chart.js` **v2.xx**
I modified his good code to work with .. `chart.js` **v3.xx**

(**v3.xx** is not backwards compatible with **v2.xx**)

```js
// var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart")
const ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d"); // added '.getContext("2d")'

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["label 1", "label 2"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Label",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(159,170,174,0.8)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(232,105,90,0.8)",
      hoverBorderColor: "orange",
      scaleStepWidth: 1,
      data: [4, 5]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {  // 'legend' now within object 'plugins {}'
      legend: {
        labels: {
          color: "blue",  // not 'fontColor:' anymore
          // fontSize: 18  // not 'fontSize:' anymore
          font: {
            size: 18 // 'size' now within object 'font {}'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {  // not 'yAxes: [{' anymore (not an array anymore)
        ticks: {
          color: "green", // not 'fontColor:' anymore
          // fontSize: 18,
          font: {
            size: 18, // 'size' now within object 'font {}'
          },
          stepSize: 1,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
      x: {  // not 'xAxes: [{' anymore (not an array anymore)
        ticks: {
          color: "purple",  // not 'fontColor:' anymore
          //fontSize: 14,
          font: {
            size: 14 // 'size' now within object 'font {}'
          },
          stepSize: 1,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <!-- gets you the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.3.2 -->

<div>
  <canvas id="barChart" height="140"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you helped me  with version 3 :)

Comment: Great, it's working. Had few modification in attribute name in newer version comparing to previous ones.

Answer (score -3):

this worked for me to change label color

```
data:{
 datasets:[{
  color: '#232323'
 }]
}
```

Comment: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'color' does not exist in type 'ChartDataset<"bar", number[]>'