# Chartjs change the specific label color in x axis in callback function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i develop the program that show some data in bar chart, i use chart.js and config my data, i just want to customize the labels and make specific label bold and color red

i use callback function in (ticks) property to access value of labels

```
  xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
          fontFamily: "IRANSans",
          fontSize: 16,
          autoSkip: false,
          callback: function(value) {
              if (value === 'some_value') {
                  return (make color red)
              } else {
                  return (make color blue)
              }
          }
      }
  }]
```

when the condition equal to some_value i just want to change the color of label
please help me to correct my code :) thanks alot:)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292423/chart-js-label-color) may be helpful.

Comment: @skobaljic in normal circumstances it would be, but this is using a callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to [draw text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) with the desired styles underneath each bar.

> When drawing your own tick labels, you need to instruct Chart.js not to display the default labels. This can be done through the following definition inside the chart options.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      display: false
    }
  }],
```

> You also need to define some padding for the bottom of the chart, otherwise you won't see your custom tick labels.

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 20
  }
},
```

Please take a look at the following sample code that illustrates how to change the labels on the x-axis depending on the values.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.font = '12px Arial';
      chart.data.labels.forEach((l, i) => {
        var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[i];
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(l);        
        ctx.fillStyle = value == 60 ? 'red' : 'blue';
        ctx.fillText(value, x, yAxis.bottom + 17);
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First Dataset",
      data: [60, 59, 80, 81, 60, 55, 40],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 20
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```