# How to change chart.js axis labels color?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im trying to change the color of the axis labels. Ive tried different tutorials and tips on the net. And from stackoverflow. but none of them seem to work. Any idea on how i can change the colors?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293215/1852444

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js label color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292423/chart-js-label-color)

Comment: i have tried it, doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Since the duplicates didnt work for you I am asuming you are using v3 of the lib, in v3 the way you do this has slightly changed so you use `color` instead of `fontcolor`

```
  options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
        ticks: {
                    color: 'white'
        }
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
                    color: 'white'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'white'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is how I did it. Add the scales option in your Chart creation

```
scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          fontColor: 'black',
          fontSize: 12,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          fontColor: 'black',
          fontSize: 12,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
```

If this does not work, can you please update you question with your code. That would make it a lot easier to detect the problem.

Comment: in here? var myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );

Comment: what is inside that config?