# How to add space between legend and graph in ng2 chart?

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I would like to add space between the legend (last evaluation results) and the graph. Basically, if in my example the result is greater than 77, it will collide with the legend.
Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-radar-chart-example-etwwuh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for my example.

Yes, I've checked many solutions on the net, including other posts on this platform, but nothing is working in my current case.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the question itself. Linking to an off-site resource like stackblitz is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a plugin to increase the height. You can override the fit function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Chart,
  ChartConfiguration,
  ChartData,
  ChartType,
  Plugin,
} from 'chart.js';
import DataLabelsPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        min: 0,
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onClick: function (e) {
          return;
        },
      },
      datalabels: {
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
      },
      tooltip: {
        padding: 10,
      },
    },
    aspectRatio: 3,
  };
  barChartType: ChartType = 'line';
  barChartPlugins = [
    DataLabelsPlugin,
    <Plugin>{
      id: 'legend-padding',
      beforeInit: function (chart: Chart & { legend: { fit: Function } }) {
        // Get reference to the original fit function
        const originalFit = chart.legend.fit;

        // Override the fit function
        chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
          // Bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
          originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
          this.height += 20; // Change the height
        };
      },
    },
  ];

  barChartData: ChartData<'line'> = {
    // timestamps
    labels: ['15-05-2023', '15-05-2023', '15-05-2023'],
    datasets: [
      {
        // lasts results
        data: [77, 77, 77],
        label: 'Last evaluation results',
        backgroundColor: '#d1d9ff',
        borderColor: '#18276f',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#18276f',
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-radar-chart-example-uahe4w)

[Original Solution Nidhi Shah Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart)

Comment: Thanks a lot Naren Murali, it worked. Only downside : I had to add type 'any' in front of 'barChartPlugins' in order to be accepted by typescript. Do you have a better typing idea ?

Comment: Do you know by chance how to change the colors of the labels ? I speak about the timestamps in my case

Comment: @MC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292423/chart-js-label-color)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I saw it, but this is for the label which is the title of the graph ... I speak about the timestamp on the X axis

Comment: @MC This should work right? `xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "purple",
                        fontSize: 14,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]`

Comment: Nope ... xAxes is not even present in the ts declaration file ... what a pain this librairy. If you find the answer, could you fork the stackblitz ? PS : typing the plugin did not work but nevermind. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-radar-chart-example-wgjlzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts